# How can I add the old value of a cell before an edit in my Google Spreadsheet logger using OnEdit function?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

In a Google Spreadsheet file I am making a logger based on the OnEdit function.

Therefor I am using the following code:

```
function onEdit(e) { 
  var sName = e.source.getActiveSheet().getSheetName();  
  if(sName !== "Logging") {
    var value;
    var mA1 = e.range.getA1Notation().split(":")[0];
    var time = new Date().toTimeString();    
    if(typeof(e.value) == 'string') {
      var aCell = e.source.getRange(mA1);
      value = aCell.getValue();
      var form = "'" + aCell.getFormula();
    } else {
      value = e.value;      
    }
    var data = [sName, mA1, time, value, form];
    e.source.getSheetByName("Logging").appendRow(data);
  }
}
```

The output right now is the Sheet name where the edit has been made, the cell location, the time, the new value and form. I want to add in a column the old value before the change, but I can't figure it out. Anyone able to shed a light here?

Tried formulating some coding to add the old value, but can't make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about using a property of `oldValue` in the event object of OnEdit? For example, when your script is modified, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var data = [sName, mA1, time, value, form];
```

#### To:

```
var data = [sName, mA1, time, value, form, e.oldValue || null];
```

- In this modification, when `e.oldValue` is included in the event object, the value of `e.oldValue` is used. When `e.oldValue` is not included, `null` is used.

#### Reference:

- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)